# SQL error when running X++ class in Dynamics AX: The multi-part identifier "D.DATAAREAID" could not be bound

Tags: sql, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I am getting an SQL error when I try to run my x++ class in Microsoft Dynamics AX. I've researched the issue around this site and google with no luck.

Here is the problematic query:

```
select custTable
order by custTable.AccountNum
join dirpartytable
join personDetails
outer join address
where custTable.PartyId == dirpartytable.PartyId && //custTable.TableId == dirpartytable.TableId &&
dirPartyTable.FirstName!='' && dirPartyTable.LastName!='' &&
custTable.PartyId == personDetails.PartyId &&
dirpartytable.RecId == address.AddrRecId && dirpartytable.TableId == address.AddrTableId &&
                        custTable.BBBStoreID != '' && custTable.MainContactId != '' && custTable.CRM_AccountNum == ''
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
Error   Message (04:52:10 pm)   Cannot select a record in Customers (CustTable). Customer account: , .
The SQL database has issued an error.

Info    Message (04:52:10 pm)   SQL error description: [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "D.DATAAREAID" could not be bound.

Info    Message (04:52:10 pm)   SQL statement: SELECT A.ACCOUNTNUM,A.NAME,A.ADDRESS,A.PHONE,A.TELEFAX,A.INVOICEACCOUNT,A.CUSTGROUP,A.LINEDISC,A.PAYMTERMID,A.CASHDISC,A.CURRENCY,A.SALESGROUP,A.BLOCKED,A.ONETIMECUSTOMER,A.ACCOUNTSTATEMENT,A.CREDITMAX,A.MANDATORYCREDITLIMIT,A.DIMENSION,A.DIMENSION2_,A.DIMENSION3_,A.VENDACCOUNT,A.TELEX,A.PRICEGROUP,A.MULTILINEDISC,A.ENDDISC,A.VATNUM,A.COUNTRYREGIONID,A.INVENTLOCATION,A.DLVTERM,A.DLVMODE,A.MARKUPGROUP,A.CLEARINGPERIOD,A.ZIPCODE,A.STATE,A.COUNTY,A.URL,A.EMAIL,A.CELLULARPHONE,A.PHONELOCAL,A.FREIGHTZONE,A.CREDITRATING,A.TAXGROUP,A.STATISTICSGROUP,A.PAYMMODE,A.COMMISSIONGROUP,A.BANKACCOUNT,A.PAYMSCHED,A.NAMEALIAS,A.CONTACTPERSONID,A.INVOICEADDRESS,A.OURACCOUNTNUM,A.SALESPOOLID,A.INCLTAX,A.CUSTITEMGROUPID,A.NUMBERSEQUENCEGROUP,A.LANGUAGEID,A.PAYMDAYID,A.LINEOFBUSINESSID,A.DESTINATIONCODEID,A.GIROTYPE,A.SUPPITEMGROUPID,A.GIROTYPEINTERESTNOTE,A.TAXLICENSENUM,A.PAYMSPEC,A.BANKCENTRALBANKPURPOSETEXT,A.BANKCENTRALBANKPURPOSECODE,A.CITY,A.STREET,A.PAGER,A.SMS,A.PACKMATERIALFEELICENSENUM,A.DLVREASON,A.GIROTYPECOLLECTIONLETTER,A.SALESCALENDARID,A.CUSTCLASSIFICATIONID,A.SHIPCARRIERACCOUNT,A.GIROTYPEPROJINVOICE,A.INVENTSITEID,A.ORDERENTRYDEADLINEGROUPID,A.SHIPCARRIERID,A.SHIPCARRIERFUELSURCHARGE,A.SHIPCARRIERBLINDSHIPMENT,A.PARTYTYPE,A.PARTYID,A.SHIPCARRIERACCOUNTCODE,A.PROJPRICEGROUP,A.GIROTYPEFREETEXTINVOICE,A.SYNCENTITYID,A.SYNCVERSION,A.SALESDISTRICTID,A.SEGMENTID,A.SUBSEGMENTID,A.RFIDITEMTAGGING,A.RFIDCASETAGGING,A.RFIDPALLETTAGGING,A.COMPANYCHAINID,A.MAINCONTACTID,A.IDENTIFICATIONNUMBER,A.PARTYCOUNTRY,A.PARTYSTATE,A.GIROTYPEACCOUNTSTATEMENT,A.COMPANYTYPE_MX,A.RFC_MX,A.CURP_MX,A.STATEINSCRIPTION_MX,A.EINVOICE,A.CREDITCARDADDRESSVERIFICATION,A.CREDITCARDCVC,A.CREDITCARDADDRESSVERIFICATI292,A.CREDITCARDADDRESSVERIFICATI293,A.USECASHDISC,A.CASHDISCBASEDAYS,A.USEPURCHREQUEST,A.ANNIVERSARY,A.CHILDRENNAMES,A.MARITALSTATUS,A.PROFESSION,A.BIRTHDATE,A.SPOUSE,A.WEBCUSTOMERID,A.FIRSTNAME,A.LASTNAME,A.MIDDLENAME,A.SPOUSEBIRTHDATE,A.GENDER,A.BBBNEWNAME,A.BBBUPDATENAME,A.BBBSTOREID,A.IGNMAINCONTACTID,A.EMAIL2,A.BBB_EMAIL2,A.CRM_ACCOUNTNUM,A.IGN_FIRSTNAME,A.MODIFIEDDATETIME,A.CREATEDDATETIME,A.RECVERSION,A.RECID,B.GENERATIONALSUFFIX,B.NAME,B.SALUTATION,B.PERSONNAMEORDER,B.LANGUAGEID,B.TYPE,B.PREFIX,B.PROFESSIONALSUFFIX,B.FIRSTNAME,B.MIDDLENAME,B.LASTNAME,B.PARTYID,B.NAMEALIAS,B.MODIFIEDDATETIME,B.MODIFIEDBY,B.CREATEDDATETIME,B.CREATEDBY,B.RECVERSION,B.RECID,C.PARTYID,C.NICKNAME,C.INITIALS,C.CHILDRENNAMES,C.BIRTHDATE,C.MARITALSTATUS,C.ANNIVERSARYDATE,C.HOBBIES,C.GENDER,C.SIPECOMMUNICATIONTYPEID,C.BBB_AGEGROUP,C.BBB_INCOMELEVEL,C.BBB_RINGSIZE,C.BBB_SPOUSERINGSIZE,C.BBB_CLIENTINFORMATION,C.BBB_SIXMONTHFOLLOWUP,C.BBB_PREFERREDCONTACT,C.BBB_SPOUSE_BIRTHDAY,C.BBB_SPOUSE_NAME,C.BBB_DATASOURCE_NAME,C.BBB_DATASOURCE_DATE,C.BBB_JEWELRY_PURCHASER,C.BBB_ZIP_FOUR,C.BBB_CONVERTED_DATE,C.BBB_CONVERTED_DESC,C.BBB_CONVERTED_PROSPECT,C.BBB_IS_VAULT_MEMBER,C.BBB_EM_UNSUBSCRIBE,C.BBB_DM_UNSUBSCRIBE,C.BBB_EM_BOUNCES,C.BBB_DM_BOUNCES,C.BBB_DO_NOT_CALL,C.MODIFIEDDATETIME,C.MODIFIEDBY,C.CREATEDDATETIME,C.CREATEDBY,C.RECVERSION,C.RECID,D.ADDRTABLEID,D.ADDRRECID,D.LINENUM,D.TYPE,D.NAME,D.ADDRESS,D.PHONE,D.TELEFAX,D.COUNTRYREGIONID,D.ZIPCODE,D.STATE,D.COUNTY,D.TELEX,D.URL,D.PHONELOCAL,D.CELLULARPHONE,D.EMAIL,D.TAXGROUP,D.CITY,D.STREET,D.PAGER,D.SMS,D.LATITUDE,D.LONGITUDE,D.SALESCALENDARID,D.TIMEZONE,D.DLVTERM,D.DLVMODE,D.SHIPCARRIERID,D.SHIPCARRIERBLINDSHIPMENT,D.SHIPCARRIERACCOUNT,D.SHIPCARRIERACCOUNTCODE,D.SHIPCARRIERRESIDENTIAL,D.BBB_ZIP4,D.RECVERSION,D.RECID,A.MEMO,B.MEMO FROM  {oj CUSTTABLE A LEFT OUTER JOIN DIRPARTYTABLE B ON ((D.DATAAREAID=?) AND (((((((((A.PARTYID=B.PARTYID) AND (B.FIRSTNAME<>?)) AND (B.LASTNAME<>?)) AND (A.PARTYID=C.PARTYID)) AND (B.RECID=D.ADDRRECID)) AND (D.ADDRTABLEID=?)) AND (A.BBBSTOREID<>?)) AND (A.MAINCONTACTID<>?)) AND (A.CRM_ACCOUNTNUM=?)))},DIRPARTYTABLE B,DIRPERSONPARTYDETAIL C WHERE (A.DATAAREAID=?) AND (B.DATAAREAID=?) AND (C.DATAAREAID=?) ORDER BY A.DATAAREAID,A.ACCOUNTNUM
```

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have also found that commenting out the "outer join address" and the related where segments, the issue goes away so I'm assuming it has something to do with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens here is that the generated query doesn't include all your tables. The reason for this is weirdness in AX when combining inner and outer joins in the same query.

See [this blog post](http://bmdax.blogspot.nl/2011/05/joins-inner-outer-combined.html)

The solution would be to convert the inner join to an outer join, which will off course give you wrong results as it will return your records even if it doesn't have a matching dirpartytable or persondetails row.

If you can have customers without a partytable or persondetails row you would need to filter in your code.

Also, if you use all outer joins you need to position your where clauses more carefully.

Some examples:

```
//Works
select custTable
order by custTable.AccountNum
outer join dirpartytable
where custTable.PartyId == dirpartytable.PartyId
outer join address
// && //custTable.TableId == dirpartytable.TableId &&
where dirPartyTable.FirstName!='' && dirPartyTable.LastName!='' &&
dirpartytable.RecId == address.AddrRecId && dirpartytable.TableId == address.AddrTableId &&
                           custTable.MainContactId != '' ;//&& custTable.CRM_AccountNum == ''

//Works    
select custTable
order by custTable.AccountNum
join dirpartytable
join address
where custTable.PartyId == dirpartytable.PartyId && //custTable.TableId == dirpartytable.TableId &&
dirPartyTable.FirstName!='' && dirPartyTable.LastName!='' &&
dirpartytable.RecId == address.AddrRecId && dirpartytable.TableId == address.AddrTableId &&
                           custTable.MainContactId != '' ;//&& custTable.CRM_AccountNum == ''

//Doesnt work
select custTable
order by custTable.AccountNum
join dirpartytable
where custTable.PartyId == dirpartytable.PartyId
outer join address
// && //custTable.TableId == dirpartytable.TableId &&
where dirPartyTable.FirstName!='' && dirPartyTable.LastName!='' &&
dirpartytable.RecId == address.AddrRecId && dirpartytable.TableId == address.AddrTableId &&
                           custTable.MainContactId != '' ;//&& custTable.CRM_AccountNum == ''


//Doesnt work    
select custTable
order by custTable.AccountNum
join dirpartytable
outer join address
where custTable.PartyId == dirpartytable.PartyId && //custTable.TableId == dirpartytable.TableId &&
dirPartyTable.FirstName!='' && dirPartyTable.LastName!='' &&
dirpartytable.RecId == address.AddrRecId && dirpartytable.TableId == address.AddrTableId &&
                           custTable.MainContactId != '' ;//&& custTable.CRM_AccountNum == ''
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to AX09 but I think your problem is because you're mixing company-specific tables with non-company specific tables. `DirPartyTable` has a property called `SaveDataPerCompany=No`, which means there is no `DataAreaId` column, while `CustTable` does.

I can't remember the format of the address table and if it's company-specific or not, but I'd look at that.  Also, check into [cross-company selects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc518738.aspx).